# Is the idea of a multiverse considered metaphysics?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology, definitions

I know that metaphysics has to do with the fundamental nature of reality. I am just not sure if a multiverse is considered fundamental

Answer (score 1):

- One might want to check out the very similar post [Should multiverse theories be rebranded as meta physics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8389/should-multiverse-theories-be-rebranded-as-meta-physics).

I will not dare to answer your question myself, since I have no clear definition of metaphysics up my sleeve. Because of this lack of experience, I can also not give you a good compendium. The following is what I found after a quick search:

- The 2 subjects you describe form the basis of some posts tagged as [Posts tagged as "metaphysical **multiverse**"](http://sententias.org/tag/metaphysical-multiverse/) by [Max Andrews](http://sententias.org/about/).
- I'll just mention another public-comments post, dealing with these issues: [Landscaping The Cosmic Garden](http://www.npr.org/blogs/13.7/2011/06/22/137282707/landscaping-the-cosmic-garden).
- There is a book called [Worlds Without End. The Many Lives of the **Multiverse**](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.7312/rube15662#) by [Mary-Jane Rubenstein](http://mrubenstein.faculty.wesleyan.edu/) which sais the following in the book's description:

> In their very efforts to sidestep **metaphysics**, theoretical physicists propose **multiverse** scenarios that collide with it and even produce counter-theological narratives.

Again: I haven't thoroughly looked through these sources. I hope you invoke on an interesting intellectual progress though, wishing you a fruitful and enjoyable contribution to science.

Answer (score 0):

Metaphysics is the name of a book by Aristotle; and not named by him; it meant simply 'after the physics'; and simply suggested that it was to be read in that order - or understood in that order. Its only much later that it had the connotation that is now generally given to it.

Aristotles metaphysics critiques the notions of his Physics - questions of Place, Time, Body, the Continuum and what is to be understood as a principle of nature ie a Law.

Given this, I'd suggest that it is in one sense, and isn't in another; which isn't that helpful...(personally I tend to think of it as esoteric physics).

Comment: "meta" means "after" in Greek.